# Opening page using a PHP header with random ID works on Edge but not chrome

Tags: php, html

I am trying to generate a random number (between 1 - 151) so I can open a page based on a randomly generated ID. The issue here is with browser compatibility because the intended functionality works on Edge but no Chrome or FireFox.

pokedex.php:

```
<form action='randomPokemon.php' >
    <button type="submit" class="toolsBtn">Random</button>
</form>
```

randomPokemon.php:

```
<?php
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'pokedex.php?pid=';
$randomid = rand(1, 151);
header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra" . mt_rand(1, 151));
unset($randomid);
exit;
?>
```

Live Demo at: http://fraserprovan.co.uk/projects/pokedex/pokedex.php

I have no idea why it works on Microsoft Edge but not other browsers. On chrome it opens the same page everytime as if the varaible $randomid doesnt change. Any advice or links to other resources will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: 
decided to do it in Javascript instead using the following function, Thanks for the suggestions.

```
function randomPokemon(){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) + 1;  
    document.location.replace('pokedex.php?pid=' + randomNum);
}
```

Comment: When I try it in Chrome and Firefox gets the same result as you do. Very odd indeed.

Comment: I dont know what the difference is about using it in edge, im scratching my head.

Comment: When calling `randomPokemon.php` the URL changes to `pokedex.php` as expected. This happens even if I paste the URL with `randomPokemon.php`.

Comment: Have you tried logging the random numbers generated to make sure something isn't whacky in the PHP? I'm getting odd, but very reproducible, behavior. I always get #82 when clicking `Random`, but I always get #39 if I access the page from the console using `location.href = "http://fraserprovan.co.uk/projects/pokedex/randomPokemon.php"`.

Comment: How would you recommend logging? I know how to write to console in javascript but not in php

Comment: Its cache. Refer [Non cached Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192590/how-to-do-a-non-cached-301-redirect)

Comment: @Pilan see original post for updated code. So I looked at what you sent but found it quite hard to follow. I found this post regarding 303 redirects: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640109/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-for-php-site

I now get this in the chrome dev tools for the script: 303 See Other (from disk cache) but the from disk cache only appears on the 2nd+ time the button is pressed. Do you see anything wrong with the way I have implemented this?

Comment: @Fraser tried `header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **absolute** URI instead, also don't leave **any space or new line** before header-statement. See this note from [php-docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Note:
>
> Most contemporary clients accept relative URIs as argument to »
>   Location:, but some older clients require an absolute URI including
>   the scheme, hostname and absolute path. You can usually use
>   $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an
>   absolute URI from a relative one yourself:
>
> ```
> <?php
> /* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
> $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
> $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
> $extra = 'mypage.php';
> header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
> exit;
> ?>
> ```

Comment: I updated the randomPokemon.php: code. Thanks for the tip. I updated the original post with the updated code. Unfortunatly same error is happening.

Comment: Try this: header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra" . mt_rand(1, 151)); instead of $randomid = rand(1, 151); if it didn't work please try using fixed number and keep me posted.

Comment: Updated this line of code, same issue. Another user mentioned caching, im just trying to understand how it works. Could be the issue.

Comment: I can see it is working on chrome now, how you fixed it?