# .htaccess: Clear Browser Cache & Redirection

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache, http-status-code-301

Use case is a Wordpress installation, with another in subdirectory setup through cPanel.
Code was generated for standard redirection of subfolder to index.html in subfolder `subDir`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^subDir$ "https\:\/\/mySite\.com\/subDir\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^subDir\/$ "https\:\/\/mySite\.com\/subDir\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
[R=301,L]
...
```

The redirect always works when clicking the jumplink in home page, `mySite.com/subDir`.

The issue is when the browser cache is completely cleared for the time interval the redirect was issued, the redirect won't work. For example, issue the redirect, and immediately proceed to clear the entire browser cache and history (for the last hour is recommended.) In testing with MS Edge, disabled LiteSpeed, chose all options in the dialog shown barring `Passwords`, `Autofill` and `Media Foundation Data`:

[image: Edge cache options]

Once that is performed, reload the base homepage to find the jumplink now redirecting to the *WP* home page, `subDir/index.php`, instead of `subDir/index.html`.

As the WP setup/theme is close to default, by that there is no [Cache-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192590/how-to-do-a-non-cached-301-redirect/12192663#12192663) code used anywhere in WP, the above behaviour is *by design* and the redirect can be easily recreated by editing the .htaccess file. For positive effect, the type of .htaccess edit may vary depending on browser, for a WP site showing in Chrome it usually amounts to the inclusion or exclusion of something fairly benign like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^subDir\/index\.php$ "https\:\/\/mySite\.com\/subDir\/index\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Once this edit is made, the jumplink *will not redirect* to `subDir/index.html` unless (my bold) the **browser cache is purged again**.

Without going down the rabbit hole of grepping 301 response headers in user caches, it would seem apt, if not somewhat inelegant, by regularly (bi-monthly / yearly etc.) editing the server .htaccess to address the rare occurrence of redirection issues *post* cleared cache by user.
Is this reasonable, or does a better method (other than a hard `mySite.com/subDir/index.html` jumplink on the home page) exist?

Comment: The issue is not whether you want to introduce such a periodic job to temporary alter your rewriting implementation. I have _never_ seen such a strategy, it appears insane. Your rewriting implementation has to be robust to situations with client side cache or without. You don't want new users having to wait for a month until they can finally access the pages, do you?

Comment: And a side note: those conditions your implemented are completely useless. They accept _anything_ , so have no purpose at all.

Comment: @arkascha:  So a 301 redirect set before a user navigates to it on clean browser on new machine won't work? The [cPanel docs](https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/domains/redirects/) don't cover this, so my research is incomplete, and permissions at cPanel are limited to the above technologies. Can a Cron job be set up for anything like this? And yes, the extra condition is useless, the point is it is enough to re-issue the request.

Comment: I can really not tell, what problem you are trying to solve here. What is this redirect supposed to be good for in the first place? _"The issue is when the browser cache is completely cleared for the time interval the redirect was issued, the redirect won't work. This is by design and the redirect can be easily recreated by editing the .htaccess file."_ - what does clearing of the browser cache, have to do with the need to _re-create_ anything in the .htaccess? Are you really talking about the _browser_ cache here - or flushing permalink settings in WP?

Comment: @Cbroe: The `subDir` site is excluded from permalinks in .htaccess. The redirect is there for many reasons, the detail of which can go to chat. The problem is why the 301 fails after user browser cache (everything including history) is cleared. As the permanence of 301 is dependent on its existence in cache, the only way I know to make the browser redirect to the desired uri is to change the .htaccess file. Question is: Is it reasonable to assume the existence of another method which ensures the 301 redirect on the site is still active next time the user clinks the link on the home page?

Comment: I still can't tell what you are actually trying to achieve here in the first place. You say this redirect was "temporary", does that mean you edit the .htaccess to sometimes have this in there, and sometimes not? If anything about this was supposed to be _temporary_, then why are you using the status code for a _permanent_ redirect?

Comment: Ehm, didn't say anything about temporary, that was @arkascha.

Comment: What do you mean then, by _"for the time interval the redirect was issued"_? _"This is by design and the redirect can be easily recreated by editing the .htaccess file"_ - why would it need "recreating", if no one removed it?

Comment: The time interval in which the .htaccess file is modified. This issues a redirect, and the browser cache is cleared. This precludes the event of the browser cache being cleared _before_ the redirect is issued. Think that could have been said differently. :P

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, added the clarification to the question.

Comment: I still don't get what the purpose of the whole thing is supposed to be. Or what clearing of the browser cache is even supposed to have to do with this.

Comment: Can still only _guess_ that you might actually want a 302 redirect, instead of a 301 one.

Comment: _Or what clearing of the browser cache is even supposed to have to do with this_: It breaks the permanent redirect. Plz fix.